# Popup says I flagged less than 5 sec ago. Next popup says I already flagged the answer

Tags: bug

I tried to flag [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28249076/729907). I had not, I believe, flagged any question or answer in quite a while. I chose the bullet "Other" (don't recall the exact bullet label) and wrote that the answer seemed to be a comment on the question and did not provide an answer.

A popup told me that I can only flag every 5 seconds. Huh? I had not flagged anything previously, for a long time.

I tried again (retyped the explanation, since there is no history retrieval). This time a popup told me that I had already flagged this answer. And yet there is no visual indication that I had flagged it, and the previous popup seemed to indicate that that flagging request failed.

Seems like a bug.  If not, feel free to ignore.

Comment: Did you check your flag history to see if you did flag it?

Comment: @psubsee2003: No. Where is my "flag history"? But even if I did in fact flag it, in spite of the message saying that I could not, the UI after that flagging does not show that I flagged it, AFAICT.

Comment: it is a link in your profile right above your name and email address, but if you want to go right to it, it should be [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/729907) (No one can see it but you and the moderators, but that is what the link should be based on your user id.

Comment: @psubsee2003: OK, so it seems I did flag it. Dunno which time, though, since I repeated the attempt (and was told each time that I could *not* flag it). Judging by the text, I think it was the second attempt that apparently succeeded - the one where the popup said that I could not flag it because I had already flagged it. ;-)